# JQuery FadeOut, Load and FadeIn

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout, jquery-effects

I've got a following code for fadeOut, load another content and fadeIn, but I've got a problem, that sometimes, when the load function is very fast, it switches the loaded content even before the timeline completely fadeOut, so the effect is a bit weird at this case. How can I prevent this?

**Note**
I want to load content immediately after click, so putting the load function into the first fadeTo callback function is not the solution. Thanks!

```
$(".switches li").click(function(evn) {
        $(".switches li").removeClass("active");
        $(evn.target).addClass("active");
        $(".timeline").fadeTo(400, 0, function(){
           $(this).css("visibility", "hidden");
        }); 
        $(".timeline").load("inc-timeline/"+evn.target.id+".html", function() {
            $(this).fadeTo(400, 100, function() {
                $(this).css("visibility", "visible");
                if(evn.target.id === "data-girls") {
                    $(".data-girls-powered").fadeIn(400);
                } else {
                    $(".data-girls-powered").fadeOut(400);
                }
            });
        });  
    });
```

Comment: Move load logic into the fadeTo callback (or use more callbacks, or use promises)

Comment: Please, read the note, I don't want to move load logic into the first fadeTo callback, because then it sometimes takes a lot of time :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `start` option of `.animate()`, `.finish()`

```
  // call `.load()` when `.fadeTo(400, 0)` starts 
  $(".timeline").finish().animate({opacity:0},{
    start: function() {
      // do asynchronous stuff; e.g., `.load()`
      $(this).load("inc-timeline/"+evn.target.id+".html", function() {
        // stop `.fadeTo(400, 0)` animation,
        // start animating to `opacity:1`
        $(this).finish().fadeTo(400, 1, function() {
          // do stuff
        });
      });
    },
    duration: 400        
  });
```

```js
$("button").click(function() {
  // call `.load()` when `.fadeTo(400, 0)` starts 
  $(".timeline").finish().animate({opacity:0},{
    start: function() {
      var el = $(this);
      // do asynchronous stuff; e.g., `.load()`
      $.Deferred(function(dfd) {
        setTimeout(function() {
          dfd.resolveWith(el)
        }, Math.floor(Math.random() * 3500))
      }).promise().then(function() {
        // stop `.fadeTo(400, 0)` animation,
        // start animating to `opacity:1`
        $(this).finish().fadeTo(400, 1, function() {
        });
      });
    },
    duration: 400        
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>click</button>
<div class="timeline">abc</div>
```

Comment: Please, read the note, I don't want to start loading content after 400ms, I want to load it immeadiately after click

Comment: @user3216673 _"I don't want to start loading content after 400ms, I want to load it immeadiately after click"_ You can `start` option of `.fadeTo()` to call `.load()` when `.fadeTo()` starts; call `.stop()` when `.load()` completes to stop `.fadeTo(400, 0)` animation, begin `.fadeTo(400, 1)` animation

Comment: fadeTo duration doesn't work, I've got no effect now, it hides immediately :(

Comment: @user3216673 See updated post. Substituted `.animate()` , which does have a `start` option, for `.fadeTo()` at `.fadeTo(400, 0)`

Comment: Okay, this seems to be the best of all solutions, but what if I would like to perform "disappearing" fadeTo even if the content is loaded? Now it stops the effect (`stop()`)

Comment: You could also substitute `.finish()` for `.stop()`; see updated post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125254/discussion-between-guest271314-and-user3216673).

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the duration of the load..to be longer than 400 milliseconds, would that help?

Comment: I don't think that load has a duration option, am I wrong?